# iOS Navigation Bar flickers black when animating

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, uinavigationbar, flicker

I have a navigation bar that gets hidden when a `UIScrollView` scrolls down and unhidden when the `UIScrollView` scrolls up. When the user "wiggles" the `scrollview`, such that the animations counteract each other, there is a black background that is visible.

I have tried setting background colors of self.view,

```
self.view.window, [[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow],
```

and tried putting in a UIView behind the navigation bar, yet none have seemed to work.

Here's the gist of the scrollView workings:

```
-(void)contractHeader
{
    if(hidden) return;

    hidden = YES;

    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone; // iOS 7 only
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}

-(void)expandHeader
{
     if(!hidden) return;

     hidden = NO;

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

}
```

If these happen in very rapid succession from the "wiggling," the black background of the navigationBar appears. Has anyone seen this and found a solution?

Comment: you want to fix navigation bar. right.?

Comment: I just want to prevent the black background from showing when the user scrolls too quickly. My navigation bar is a green color but the black background flickering looks very bad